# Openvpn server running but not answering

Tags: openvpn

My Openvpn server is not answering to the petitions on the port which is listening.

I used `nmap -sU -p 1194 <server_ip>` and it reports that openvpn is using this port under UDP protocol.

Also I used `tcpdump -i wlp3s0 udp port 1194` to check if the server is receiving petitions and all seems great, it receives the packets from the clients which are trying to connect.

Then, based on this, it is not a port problem, because packets from outside the network are arriving to the server.

It is not also a configuration problem because the packets are arriving to the correct port and the server is listening to this port, but it is not answering. Also the server is active and running, it doesn't report any problem at the logs.

I'm running out of ideas to solve it guys, can you help me?

Comment: 1) Determine where your server log files are. See, by default, /etc/openvpn/server.conf. 2) Paste relevant log file messages into your question. 3) Consider increasing log verbosity. 4) Paste relevant parts of your client-side log, too.

Comment: I ended remaking all the VPN and it worked, i have no idea of what was wrong